# Vuejs "TypeError: devices.push is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

Estou tentando dar um push pra dentro de um Array, mas ele está dando esse erro: "TypeError: devices.push is not a function"

```
let device = this.$store.getters['bluetooth/Device'].UUID

let devices = firebase.getValue('/connected_devices')
let found = false
if(devices == null)
devices = []

for(let i = 0; i < devices; i++){
   if(device.mac == devices[i].mac){
      device = devices[i]
      found = true
   }
}

if(!found)
this.devices[i].push(device)

device.pi = 1234
device.teste = 4321
firebase.setValue('/connected_devices', devices)
```

Comment: O que o seu devices retorna ? ele está caindo na condição == null?

Comment: Aqui `this.devices` você referência a instância do vue. Se você deseja usar a variável do método remova o `this`

Answer (score 1):

Dei uma lida no código, e percebi que você esta tentando acessar a variavel `i` fora do escopo do for, além de tentar acessar `this.devices`.

Estas duas variáveis estão causando seu typeError

Tente o seguinte

```
if(!found)
    devices.push(device)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que você está referenciado a instância do `Vue` e não a variável `devices` que está dentro do seu método. Se deseja referenciar a variável devices dentro do método remova o `this`

Caso queira mesmo referenciar uma variável na instância adicone ao método data a propriedade devices.

```
data () {
 return {
   devices : []
 }
}
```